# Keras: Vector regression: ValueError:can not squeeze dim[1]

Tags: keras, tensorflow, regression, nlp

I'm trying to create a NLP model which takes `x_train_padded_2` (padded/tokenized text sequences) as input and try to approximate `Y_train_embedding_2` (dense embedded sentences).

Input/target types and dimensions:

```
print(x_train_padded_2.shape)
print(type(x_train_padded_2[0][0]))
(6960, 50)
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

```
print(Y_train_embedding_2.shape)
print(type(Y_train_embedding_2[0][0]))

(6960, 16)
<class 'numpy.float32'>
```

The model architcture (the embedding layer is pre-trained):

```
model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    embedding,
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(embedding_dim)
])
embedding.trainable = False
model_2.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])

history_2 = model.fit(x_train_padded_2, Y_train_embedding_2, epochs=num_epochs, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[earlyStopping], verbose=1)
```

```
model_2.summary()

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 50, 16)            16000     
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_1 ( (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 16)                272       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 16)                272       
=================================================================
Total params: 16,544
Trainable params: 544
Non-trainable params: 16,000
_________________________________________________________________
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:543 train_step  **
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:406 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:603 update_state
        matches = self._fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:3244 sparse_categorical_accuracy
        y_true = array_ops.squeeze(y_true, [-1])
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:180 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py:507 new_func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:4145 squeeze
        return gen_array_ops.squeeze(input, axis, name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:9875 squeeze
        "Squeeze", input=input, squeeze_dims=axis, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:744 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:595 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3327 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1817 __init__
        control_input_ops, op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1657 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 16 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,16].
```

Do you have any suggestions?